# Localization of decimal point in CurrencyTextBox

Tags: zend-framework, localization, dojo, zend-form

I am setting the localization for Dojo with

```
$locale = new Zend_Locale();
$locale->setLocale('de_AT');
```

and

```
$this->view->dojo()->setDjConfigOption('locale', 'de_AT')
```

in the Zend Framework.

But when I use a Form with CurrencyTextBox (in a Zend_Dojo_Form class) I have to use a dot for entering a decimal point instead of a komma, which is wrong.

Any idea why this doesn't work properly? Is this a bug of Dojo?

Comment: I don't know what Zend does with the locale, but Dojo uses a syntax like 'de-at', not 'de_AT'

Comment: Thank's! That was the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
$this->view->dojo()->setDjConfigOption('locale', 'de-at')
```

Answer (score 0):

The line should be (AT not in capitals):

```
$this->view->dojo()->setDjConfigOption('locale', 'de_at')
```